# removing the scroll bars and borders from the web browser object

Tags: vba, webbrowser-control, powerpoint

I have a powerpoint that is using a web browser object. The trouble is that the scrollbars on the web browser object are always there, regardless of whether or not they are needed. Is there some way to remove the scroll bars?

I have tried adding:

```
WebBrowser.Document.body.Scroll = "no"
```

but that makes the object stop working all together.

Also, the object has a thin light colored (i think it is white but it is hard to tell) border around it. Since most of my presentation is black this does not blend well though i have set the background color of the html displayed to be black. Is there a way to get rid of the border as well?

if they cannot be done with vba can they be done at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My understanding is no, this is not possible. I dislike the scroll bar, but it's a part of IE and I don't see any way to remove it without completely disabling functionality as you have already seen.

Answer (score 1):

JimmyPena,

I did it. After some tests I discovered that if I set the image to webbrowser and try to set other Document.Body properties in the same "f5" execution it didn't work.

If you try to use "f8", it works, ironically.

I think it is because that webbrowser component cannot set some properties after loading an object.

Sooooo, i tried to make an HTML file in which my object (in my case, an gif image) was set and all properties was set as well, including scroll removal, margin removal and border removal.

You can see my codes below.

HTML (test.html):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body style="overflow: hidden; margin: 0; border: 0;">
    <img src="Assets/loading-small.gif" />
</body>
</html>
```

VBA:

```
Sub abaSV_showLoadingIcon()
    AbaSV.WebBrowser1.Visible = True

    AbaSV.WebBrowser1.Navigate ThisWorkbook.path & "\test.html"
End Sub
```

I think that should help you, JimmyPena and uncertaintea.

SeeYa!

Answer (score 0):

Your idea works just fine, except for the VBA part.

So what I did is to creat a html file as you did, assigning the properties and calling the gif image.

Then in VBA i used the following code (in the sheet where the webborser can be found):

```
Private Sub worksheet_activate()
WebBrowser1.Navigate "insert html file path.html"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by applying in the html file this code under the `<head>` tag:

```
<style type="text/css">
html {
overflow:hidden;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Document.Body.Scroll = "No" to disable scroll bar in Webbrowser

```
Option  Explicit 
Private Sub
UserForm_Activate()
WebBrowser1.Navigate "C:-Download-P.gif"
End Sub

Private Sub 
WebBrowser1_DocumentComplete(ByVal pDisp As Object, URL As Variant)
With WebBrowser1
. Width = 80 
. Height = 80 
. Document.Body.Scroll = "No"
End With
End Sub
```